# Java: Is there a simple way to get cookie by name?

Tags: java, cookies

I've searched for solutions on how to get cookies by their name and all solutions point to using `for-loops` and `if` statements. See code below.

```
for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    if (cookie.getName().equals("<NAME>")) {
        // do something here
    } 
    if (cookie.getName().equals("<ANOTHER_NAME>")) {
        // do something here
    } 
    // and so on...
}
```

Is there any simpler way to get the value by their name without having to do the loops and if's?

I need to make some "certain" processing for certain cookies I would want to retrieve Plus, I don't want to traverse through every cookie! There could be 10 or more and all I need is just three or something.

Comment: Put the cookies into a `Map<String, Cookie>` (or `Multimap`).

Comment: Oh, that could actually work :D I'll try it right away! Thanks :D

Comment: Note to voters: Don't downvote simply because this is a beginner-level question. This is properly formatted and clearly stated with the asker showing an example of their attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic (as suggested by [Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139010/matt-ball) in the *comments*) would be:

```
// ...
Map<String, Cookie> cookieMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    cookieMap.put(cookie.getName(), cookie);
}

Cookie firstRequiredCookie = cookieMap.get("<NAME>");
// do something with firstRequiredCookie 
Cookie nextRequiredCookie = cookieMap.get("<ANOTHER_NAME>");
// do something with nextRequiredCookie 
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone! :D Forget my follow-up question, I get it now :D THANK YOU! I could've upvote the answer but my rep doesn't allow me to vote yet.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie names are not unique, so using a cookie name as a map key is not an ideal approach.

Since cookie names are not unique, that's probably why this `Java API` was never updated to provide a `getCookieByName()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively in modern Java:

```
Map<String, String> cookieMap = 
                Arrays.stream(request.getCookies())
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Cookie::getName, Cookie::getValue));
```